# What is this part that flew off of the car?

Tags: wheels, part-identification, saab

[image]

While driving a 2004 Saab 93, I heard something that sounded like a baseball card stuck in a bike spoke. I pulled over to see what it was, and this metal piece snapped off and flew out from what I think was the driver's side front tire. The car brakes and drives normally without it.

What does this part go to?

Comment: Its a brake caliper anti rattle clip. One of the retainer tangs broke off. Buy a new one, they are cheap and easy to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a part of the brakes. It looks like a spring which holds brakes in place or keeps them tight.